# Rip files from data DVD (not actual DVD format) with command line (Linux-based OS)

Tags: linux, command-line, ripping

I have a pile of DVDs. Some are actual playable DVDs with titles and chapters, and some are just data discs, with a collection of .wmv or .avi files. I can use Handbrake to easily rip the actual DVDs, but what can I use to automate the ripping of these data discs?

According to the Handbrake docs, I can pass "-t 0" to tell it to scan all the titles, but if I do that with one of the data discs, it only rips the first file.

I'm guessing it'll be a multi-step process, where I have to loop through the files on the disc; but that's the problem I'm having, is detecting if it's a proper DVD movie or not, and if not, looping through the files.

My only requirements are that it has to be command line, and it has to work on a Linux-based OS (in my case, Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is easy: If the disc has .VOB files, it's a movie disc and use Handbrake. For anything else, just copy the files to your destination. They don't need ripped or converted.

Comment: So I just found the isoinfo utility, which lists out the directories and files, so I grepped out .vob to test if it's a movie disc. That works great, now I just need to figure out the syntax for looping through the files on the disc and copying them.

Comment: Once the disc is mounted, the cp command should be all you need.